# Magento 2: Adding Custom SKU for simple products in Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, simple-product, sku

I am looking for a way to add custom SKU to the simple products which magento automatically creates when you create "configuartions" for a configurable product.

As pictured in the attachement, there's currently no way to add "custom" SKUs for the sub products.

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento allows you to edit the SKUs once the child products are generated.

[image: Product Configurations]

You are also able to edit the SKUs after the configurable product has been saved, just open the child product from the catalog and edit the SKU there.

Comment: interesting. on your screenshot I can see you can edit all SKUs at once. on my side they are not editable from that table I have to edit them one by one to change the sku...

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the simple products first(set the SKUs you want) and then go to create the Configurable one.

That way you will be able to select which simple ones from the list on the Configurations.